# Weird image aspect ratio in Google Chrome

Tags: css, google-chrome, flexbox

This is a weird CSS problem i stumbled on. It only happens in Google Chrome (I tested only Firefox and Google Chrome, and only Google Chrome have this problem).

```css
.product {
 display: grid;
 grid-template-columns: 35% 65%;
 justify-content: center;
 align-items: center;
}
.imgcontainer {
 display:grid;
 grid-template-rows: 75% 25%;
 grid-template-columns: 20px 1fr 20px;
 grid-row: 1 / span 2;
 grid-gap: 5px;
 width: 100%;
 height: 100%;
}
.imgcontainer.solo .mainimgcontainer {
 grid-row: 1 / span 2;
}
.mainimgcontainer { 
 max-height: 100%;
 text-align: center;
 grid-column: 1 / span 3;
 align-items: center;
 justify-content: center;
}
.restimgcontainer { 
 display: flex;
 max-height: 100%;
 grid-row: 2;
 grid-column: 2;
 overflow: hidden;
 justify-content: flex-start;
 align-items: flex-start;
}
.restimgcontainer img {
 display: block;
 cursor: pointer;
 border: 1px solid gray;
 box-sizing: border-box;
 object-fit: scale-down;
    flex: 0 0 auto;
 max-width: 100%;
 max-height: 100%;
 height: auto;
 width: auto;
}
.mainimgcontainer img {
 cursor: pointer;
 max-width: 100%;
 max-height: 100%;
}
.centercontainer {
 width: 100%;
 display: flex;
 flex-flow: column;
 align-items: center;
}
/*below is for styling*/
.productcontainer.noselect {
 display: block;
}
.productcontainer.nostock .message {
 position: absolute;
 width: 100%;
 height: 100%;
 display: flex;
 align-items: center;
 justify-content: center;
 z-index: 1;
}
.productcontainer {
 display: grid;
 grid-template-columns: 20px 1fr;
}
.productcontainer, .restcontainer {
 border: 1px solid #ccc;
 border-radius: 5px;
 margin: 10px;
 background-color: #f9f9f9;
 text-align: center;
 width: 90%;
 max-width: 700px;
 padding: 8px;
}
.productcontainer:hover {
 border: 1px solid #FE5A1D;
}
.control {
 display: table;
 height: 100%;
 width: 20px;
 grid-row: 2;
 background-color: gray;
 border-radius: 10px;
 padding: 30% 25%;
 text-align: center;
 box-sizing: border-box;
}
.control > div {
 display: table-cell;
    vertical-align: middle;
    text-align:center;
}
.control.left {
 border-radius: 5px 0 0 5px;
}
.control.right {
 border-radius: 0 5px 5px 0;
 grid-column: 3;
}
.product header, footer {
 display: flex;
 flex-wrap: wrap;
 grid-column: 2;
 padding: 10px 20px;
}
footer.column {
 flex-flow: column;
 align-items: flex-start;
}
footer.column .variation {
 align-self: flex-end;
}
footer.column .variation.solo {
 align-self: flex-start;
}
footer .showprice {
 text-align: right;
 flex-grow: 1;
 align-self: flex-end;
}
.product header {
 flex-wrap: wrap-reverse;
}
.product h2, p {
 margin: 0 5px;
 text-align: left;
}
.product h3 {
 margin: 5px;
}
.variation {
 display: grid;
 grid-template-columns: auto auto;
 grid-gap: 5px;
 align-self: flex-start;
}
.variation :nth-child(2n+1){
 text-align: right;
}
.variation :nth-child(2n){
 text-align: left;
}
.desc {
 display: flex;
 flex-grow: 1;
 flex-flow: column;
 align-items: flex-start;
}
.productcontainer.noselect .finalinfo {
 text-align: left;
 align-self: flex-start;
}
.finalinfo {
 text-align: right;
 flex-grow: 1;
 align-self: flex-end;
}
.toright {
 align-self: flex-end;
}
```

```html
<div class="centercontainer">
 <div class="productcontainer noselect">
  <div class="product">
   <div class="imgcontainer">
    <div class="mainimgcontainer"><img id="displayimg" src="http://41.media.tumblr.com/eeec8092766317ca3d81c6dc7f2991ed/tumblr_nnqhzk72TO1slhhf0o1_1280.jpg"></div>
    <div class="control left" style="display: none;"><div> ❮ </div></div>
    <div class="restimgcontainer">
     
     <img id="rest0" src="http://41.media.tumblr.com/eeec8092766317ca3d81c6dc7f2991ed/tumblr_nnqhzk72TO1slhhf0o1_1280.jpg">
     
    </div>
    <div class="control right" style="display: none;"><div> ❯ </div></div>
   </div>
   <header>
    <div class="desc">
     <h2>Nike Hoodie (Long Sleeve)</h2>
     <p>Tan</p>
     <h3 id="stock">Stock left: 450</h3>
     <h3 id="ppu">Price per unit: RM 139.99</h3>
    </div>
   </header>
   <footer class="column">
    <div class="variation solo">
     <div>Quantity: </div><input class="setwidth" oninput="updateprice()" id="quan" min="1" max="450" step="1" value="1" name="quantity" type="number">
     
     
     
      
       <div>Color: </div>
       <select name="Color" class="setwidth" oninput="updatesel()">
        
        <option value="Black" selected="selected">Black</option>
        
        <option value="White">White</option>
        
        <option value="Gray">Gray</option>
        
        <option value="Red">Red</option>
        
       </select>
      
       <div>Size: </div>
       <select name="Size" class="setwidth" oninput="updatesel()">
        
        <option value="XS" selected="selected">XS</option>
        
        <option value="S">S</option>
        
        <option value="M">M</option>
        
        <option value="L">L</option>
        
        <option value="XL">XL</option>
        
        <option value="XXL">XXL</option>
        
        <option value="3XL">3XL</option>
        
       </select>
      
     
     
    </div>
    <div class="finalinfo">
     <h3 id="totalp">Total price: RM 139.99</h3>
    </div>
    <input class="toright" value="Add to Cart" type="submit">
   </footer>
  </div>
 </div>
</div>
```

[JSFiddle Link](http://jsfiddle.net/ktrh8hwq/2)

Image below is the expected results and Google Chrome results, the bottom left image container (which is used as image slider) will display a list of images in a row, in Firefox, it display exactly as the expected results.

But in Google Chrome, the results were different, the width is 100% of what its parent width is. Resulting the image sliders only able to show 1 image at a time.

Is this Google Chrome's CSS problem? Is there any workaround?

[image]

Some workaround/problems I've found:

- If you inspect element and untick and tick the width/height related CSS code in that element, the problem will be gone.
- If there is no select element on the right panel, it will have no problem.

Comment: You're using percentage heights. There are rendering variations among major browsers *when you don't define heights on the parents of children with percentage heights*.

Comment: @Michael_B problem is that my left panel is using % for height (75% for top part and 25% for bottom), if i set percentage height for them, it will messed up the view and causing the ACTUAL height more than it should be

Answer (score 0):

Add:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
```

before the `<html>` tag

Comment: I'm sorry, but that was included in my website and it does not help much at all